# React refresh not working, Cannt get component error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, react-redux

I'm using browserhistory for routing , But i have an error while reload the component. Instead i used hashhistory for route,but url contains hash which isn't remove from the url. But refresh working on hash. I want to make routing with refresh without hash in url?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { homeReducer } from 'src/reducers/homeReducer';

// Import the components used as po
import auth from 'src/common/auth.js';
import Login from './login.jsx';
import Homepage from './homepage.jsx';
import Signup from './signup.jsx';
import UserHomepage from 'src/containers/user/homepage.jsx';

// Creates the Redux reducer with the redux-thunk middleware, which allows us
// to do asynchronous things in the actions
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(homeReducer);

// check if the path is login that way we can apply specific logic to display/render the path we want to
function checkAuth(nextState, replace) {

}

// Mostly boilerplate, except for the Routes. These are the po you can go to,
// which are all wrapped in the App component, which contains the navigation etc
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={UserHomepage} />
      <Route path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="*" component={Homepage} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Guys i made a solution after research few sites, Its pretty simple.

just add this one line in your web pack config,

   ' historyApiFallback: true '. this save my whole day